# Double borders div should merge css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz2vyrqp/) you'll see that the borders won't merge.
css:

```
div{
    float:left;
    background-color:moccasin;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid tomato;
}
```

The amount of divs is random, and I can only give it 1 class/id.

Also keep in mind that the page can be resized and the amount of divs on a row can change.

I've tried `margin-left:1px;` and last-child/nth-child() selectors but they don't work when you resize the screen or it still gives unwanted border.

**edit:** I can NOT move the divs for a single pixel, when I give the divs `margin-left:-1px;` and give the first div `margin-left:1px;` I'll get unwanted results in the next rows.

Comment: They won't merge because that's not how borders work on non-table elements.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just add to the div

```
margin-top: -1px;
margin-left: -1px;
```

check the following example:

```css
div{
    float:left;
    background-color:moccasin;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid tomato;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION WITH JS**
Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/hz2vyrqp/8/)

CSS:

```
div{
float:left;
background-color:moccasin;
width:100px;
height:100px;    
border-bottom:1px solid tomato;
border-right:1px solid tomato;
}
div:first-child{
border-left:1px solid tomato;
}
div.first-row {
border-top: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var borderCollapse = function() {
var div = $('div');
var divWidth = 0;
var rows = 1;
div.each(function() {
var that = $(this);
var div = $('div');
var width = div.parent().width();
var thisWidth = $(this).width();

if (divWidth < width) {    
    that.prev().not('div:first-child').css({'border-left':'0'});
    divWidth += parseInt(thisWidth);        
} else { 
    that.prev().css({'border-left':'1px solid tomato'});
    divWidth = 2 * thisWidth;
    rows += 1;        
}

if (rows <= 1) {
    that.prev().addClass('first-row');
} else {
    that.prev().removeClass('first-row');
}

});
}

borderCollapse();

$(window).resize(function() {
  borderCollapse();
});
```

Comment: I can't move the divs, the width and position is as it is, and when I add 1px to the first child I'll get this result: http://jsfiddle.net/hz2vyrqp/3/

Comment: @Nick why you need that margin on the first-child ?

Comment: @Danko To restore the div to it's proper position.

Comment: @Nick why don't padding the container ?

Comment: What's the benefit of using JS in this case when the CSS alone appears to work perfect?

Answer (score 15):

We can simulate collapsed borders with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px tomato` *instead* of a border; add a 1px left and bottom margin to align correctly.

This works because the box shadow is naturally overlapped; it does not take up space on its own. We reveal only the desired amount of shadow with the left and bottom margin.

#### With a 1px "border"

```css
div {
  float: left;
  background-color: moccasin;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px tomato;
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px; 
 /* the margin provides a little nudge as 
 box shadow won't take up space like a border 
 */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

#### With a 5px "border"

```css
div {
  float: left;
  background-color: moccasin;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px tomato;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px; 
 /* the margin provides a little nudge as 
 box shadow won't take up space like a border 
 */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```