# Create table year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my table/grid: [image: this]. This have 365 divs, 1 per day, created with js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < daysInThisYear(); i++) {
        $('#año').append('<div class="dia" id="div' + i +'" /> ');
    }
})
```

This detects if 365 or 366 days:

```
function daysInThisYear() {
  return isLeapYear() ? 366 : 365;
}

function isLeapYear() {
     return currentYear % 400 === 0 || (currentYear % 100 !== 0 && currentYear % 4 === 0);
}
```

okay, i have my grid it's ok, but i want to put days and months, like this: [image: this]. If month have 31 days, creates 31 squares, and everything together, without separations, how can i do this? And put number of the day at left and letter of month at top, idk how to to this, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried arranging the months so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes i tried some shapes but the result was not good, i will try more of course, but I wanted to know if someone knew how to do it and have it optimized, since I have no experience and would like to do my best, thanks.

Comment: @JaumeSastre Take a look of my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

One strategy could be store number of days in a array and get the total days in each one of them.

It would be something like:

```
var totalDaysOfMonth = [31, isLeapYear() ? 29: 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

to make a grid as you want, you could append one div per month, taking the total days of the array, here a idea:

https://jsbin.com/joficawofi/edit?html,css,js,output

Here other way to get total days of each month: [What is the best way to determine the number of days in a month with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315760/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-with-javascript)

Comment: Why not simply `var totalDaysOfMonth = [31, isLeapYear() ? 29: 28, 31, ...]`?

Comment: With your jsbin says     "error"
    "@siqizowoyo.js:28:19
    "

Comment: @JaumeSastre I fixed it up

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks for the recommendation, I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, it works @JoseRojas but, how can i get same border weight? That is, dont get this: https://gyazo.com/60734185b2bd2d1784df2250b9cd018f, all borders same width, thx.

Comment: @JaumeSastre Try putting margin: -1px at the class `.dia`, here some others strategies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228686/double-borders-div-should-merge-css

Answer (score 0):

This code will create the table like you want.

I use the `Date` object to detect leap year since the logic is already provided. By attempting to set the date to Feb 29 for a give year it will leave it as Feb 29 if it is a leap year or change it to March 1 for non-leap years.

```js
function isLeapYear(year) {
  var resp = new Date(year,1,29).getDate()===29;;
  return resp;
}


var daysOfMonth = [31, isLeapYear((new Date().getFullYear())) ? 29: 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var monthLetters = 'JFMAMJJASOND'.split('');


var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
var dayEl, monthEl;
var monthEl = document.createElement('div');
monthEl.className = "calendar-month";
tempEl = document.createElement('div');
tempEl.className = "calendar-month__title";
monthEl.appendChild(tempEl);

for(let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  dayEl = document.createElement('div');
  dayEl.className = 'calendar-day calendar-day__number';
  dayEl.textContent = i;
  monthEl.appendChild(dayEl);
}

calendarEl.appendChild(monthEl);
daysOfMonth.forEach(
  function(days, month) {
    monthEl = document.createElement('div');
    monthEl.className = "calendar-month";
    monthEl.setAttribute('data-month', month+1);
    tempEl = document.createElement('div');
    tempEl.className = "calendar-month__title";
    tempEl.textContent = monthLetters[month];
    monthEl.appendChild(tempEl);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
      dayEl = document.createElement('div');
      dayEl.className = 'calendar-day';
      dayEl.setAttribute('data-date', i+1);
      monthEl.appendChild(dayEl);
    }
    calendarEl.appendChild(monthEl);
  }
);
```

```css
.calendar-month {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20px;
}

.calendar-day {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.calendar-month__title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.calendar-day__number {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

With a little extra work you could get the width of the borders to work correctly, but this gets you most of the way there.